# Options for passing method names to a state change object

Tags: ios

I've got a state driven class which changes state depending upon what happens. The class has a state property which is getting called from numerous places which are sprinkled throughout the code in various methods.

Consequently its not easy/obvious to spot what the state change logic is, so I was thinking of centralizing the state changes in a dedicated method, something along the lines of the following pseudo code

```
- (void) updateState: (Param) action
{
   switch (self.currentState)
     case: EStateA: 
           if (action == connectionSuccesful)
              self.currentState = EStateB;
           else
              self.currentState = EStateC;
     break;
}


- (void) delegateCallbackConnectionSuccess
{
    [self updateState: Param];
}
```

So the updateState method needs to know what action occurred in order to change state, an action is encapsulated as a method, hence the updateState methods needs to know what method is calling it.

So my question is how best to implement this, what type should Param be?
What are the options? SEL, @selector, NSInvocation, other things?

TIA

(Implementing a full blown state pattern seems overkill, unless its easy in iOS)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the methods pass the state into updateState:?

E.g.

```
typedef enum {
    EStateA,
    EStateB
} EState;

- (void) updateState: (EState) newState {
    switch (self.currentState): {
        ...
    }
    self.currentState = newState;
}

- (void) delegateCallbackConnectionSuccess {
    [self updateState:EStateB];
}
```

Comment: That way each method needs to know what state comes next, while centralizing it means only the state method itself needs to know how to progress, which is the point of centralizing it in the first place  - decoupling knowledge of how to transition away from each individual method into only one method so its easy to both read and maintain.